# I am trying to import gensim, pandas and numpy in my django project but getting import error

Tags: django, pandas, numpy, gensim

I am getting an import error as i try to import gensim, pandas and numpy in django views.py . It works fine in shell.
How can I import them in views.py. I have installed the libraries in virtual environment.

Comment: Please, provide with the error, command that you've ran and output of echo $(pip freeze) in virtual environment.

Comment: share error please

Comment: Unable to import 'gensim'

Comment: I installed gensim in my virtual environment. when I run import gensim command in manage.py shell it works but the import in views.py file shows error. How to solve it

Comment: If it's not working when the `views.py` is run, as from your web server, then the web server is not launching the right `python`/environment. Edit your question to show more information about the exact way `views.py` is invoked – including web server used & its configuration – and the exact text of the error you see, and where/how that error appears.

Comment: Thanks ,its solved, error was with python environment.